# approximate time example: ros::Subscriber’ has no member named ‘registerCallback’

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I compile approximate time example then get this error what should I do?

```
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:38:0,
                 from /home/ardi/aerobone_ws/src/time_sub_handler/src/time_node.cpp:13:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h: In instantiation of ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&, F8&) [with F0 = ros::Subscriber; F1 = ros::Subscriber; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F8 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<serial_handler::chemsensor_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >]’:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:18:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&) [with F0 = ros::Subscriber; F1 = ros::Subscriber; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<serial_handler::chemsensor_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:295:18:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&) [with F0 = ros::Subscriber; F1 = ros::Subscriber; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<serial_handler::chemsensor_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:288:18:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = ros::Subscriber; F1 = ros::Subscriber; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<serial_handler::chemsensor_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:281:18:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = ros::Subscriber; F1 = ros::Subscriber; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<serial_handler::chemsensor_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:274:18:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = ros::Subscriber; F1 = ros::Subscriber; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<serial_handler::chemsensor_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:267:18:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = ros::Subscriber; F1 = ros::Subscriber; F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<serial_handler::chemsensor_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:260:18:   required from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&) [with F0 = ros::Subscriber; F1 = ros::Subscriber; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<serial_handler::chemsensor_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:160:18:   required from ‘message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::Synchronizer(const Policy&, F0&, F1&) [with F0 = ros::Subscriber; F1 = ros::Subscriber; Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<serial_handler::chemsensor_<std::allocator<void> >, sensor_msgs::NavSatFix_<std::allocator<void> > >]’
/home/ardi/aerobone_ws/src/time_sub_handler/src/time_node.cpp:100:63:   required from here
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:240:33: error: ‘class ros::Subscriber’ has no member named ‘registerCallback’
      input_connections_[0] = f0.registerCallback(boost::function<void(const M0Event&)>(boost::bind(&Synchronizer::template cb<0>, this, _1)));
                              ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h:38:0,
                 from /home/ardi/aerobone_ws/src/time_sub_handler/src/time_node.cpp:13:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:241:33: error: ‘class ros::Subscriber’ has no member named ‘registerCallback’
      input_connections_[1] = f1.registerCallback(boost::function<void(const M1Event&)>(boost::bind(&Synchronizer::template cb<1>, this, _1)));
                              ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
time_sub_handler/CMakeFiles/time_subs.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'time_sub_handler/CMakeFiles/time_subs.dir/src/time_node.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [time_sub_handler/CMakeFiles/time_subs.dir/src/time_node.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2785: recipe for target 'time_sub_handler/CMakeFiles/time_subs.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [time_sub_handler/CMakeFiles/time_subs.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377491/approximate-time-example:-ros::subscriber%E2%80%99-has-no-member-named-%E2%80%98registercallback%E2%80%99/) by [anonymous73997](https://answers.ros.org/users/73997/anonymous73997/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-05-02**:
"*what should I do?*" — to begin with, you could format your question correctly using the `101010` button

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-03**:\

> "*what should I do?*" — to begin with, you could format your question correctly using the `101010` button

@abhishek47kashyap: there doesn't seem to be a need to get snarky immediately here.

It seems this is @ard17's first post: could we please try to help new users instead?

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2021-05-03**:
Sorry @ard17, I realize my comment could be more constructive! @gvdhoorn, will do better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its solved, i use wrong subscriber

---

Originally posted by [anonymous73997](https://answers.ros.org/users/73997/anonymous73997/) with karma: 16 on 2021-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-03**:
Thanks for reporting your solution @ard17.

Could you please:

- not delete questions which have an actual answer?
- expand your description of your solution a bit? What was it that you actually had to change? What did you have before (ie: when you couldn't compile your node) and what do you have now?

Being clear about how you solved your problem will help future readers avoid the same problem and is much appreciated.

Thanks.